# Detect Directory Listing Vulnerability

Tags: php

I have this link http://test.com/images/

Can we find out whether Directory above has 'directory Listing vulnerability' exit or not by using PHP. I tried following code.

```
    $contents = file_get_contents("http://test.com/images/");  
    preg_match_All("|href=[\"'](.*?)[\"']|", $contents, $hrefs);  
    var_dump($hrefs);  
    echo $contents;
```

it return me directory list but it can also possible that directory contain some index page with same content so, what will be the better way to handle this.

Comment: I don't think there's any way for the client to tell whether the page was created by an index file or automatically by directory listing.

Comment: This post on superuser.com can be helpful, although the results aren't reliable http://superuser.com/questions/299533/how-do-you-remotely-check-if-http-directory-listing-is-enabled-on-linux